# Aggregate data for months in chart.js - PHP, MySQL, JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I'm newbie to js and data aggregating for charts and it would be great to know how to aggregate data in a chart collecting them for months. In the example I'm trying to sum the money data for each employee id for months but the result is always passed like singular queries.

Here it is my code in js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/**
 * call the data.php file to fetch the result from db table.
 */
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8888/site/function/data.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var importo = {
            TRCLRT76T08F704F : [],
            NGLLSN80T03F839Y : []
        };

        var len = data.length;


        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (data[i].cf == "TRCLRT76T08F704F") {
                importo.TRCLRT76T08F704F.push(data[i].importo);
            }
            else if (data[i].cf == "NGLLSN80T03F839Y") {
                importo.NGLLSN80T03F839Y.push(data[i].importo);
            }
        }

        //get canvas
        var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");

        var data = {
            labels : ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "TRCLRT76T08F704F importo",
                    data : importo.TRCLRT76T08F704F,
                    backgroundColor : "blue",
                    borderColor : "lightblue",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                },
                {
                    label : "NGLLSN80T03F839Y importo",
                    data : importo.NGLLSN80T03F839Y,
                    backgroundColor : "green",
                    borderColor : "lightgreen",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            title : {
                display : true,
                position : "top",
                text : "Line Graph",
                fontSize : 18,
                fontColor : "#111"
            },
            legend : {
                display : true,
                position : "bottom"
            }
        };

        var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
            type : "line",
            data : data,
            options : options
        } );

    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here it is the function to call the db in data.php

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT cf, mese, importo FROM table WHERE `anno` = '2017' AND `importo` > '0' ORDER BY stamp_start");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hi @giuseppe! Can you post the result of your query ? I think you should group by month in your select statement

Comment: I've tried to group in the "SELECT" statement but what I want is to have on the X-axis 12 months and on the Y-axis the sum of the profit of the month for that ID. My js script has to take all the prices for that months, summing and print on a point on my chart corresponding to that month. For now this is my parsed output: 

[
{
"cf": "PRDPRI78S30D388J",
"mese": "02",
"importo": "400"
},

and so on. What I want is to sum the profit for the month for that specific ID

Hope to be clear